# Spring Data Neo4j Relationships not working correctly

Tags: spring, kotlin, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am fairly new to neo4j coming from a relational data background. I'm having issues creating a spring service to interact with my neo4j database.

In my database I have a node 'type' / label called `Row` which has a hierarchical parent child relationship to another `Row` node

I defined my relationship like the following:

```
MATCH 
    (parent:Row),
    (child:Row)
WHERE
    child.parentUuid = parent.uuid
CREATE (parent)-[:ParentChild]->(child)
```

In Spring, my Row Entity's relationship is defined as:

```
@Node
data class Row(
     //fields

     @Relationship(type = "ParentChild", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
     var children: List<Row> = emptyList(),
) {}
```

My relationships appear to be working correctly when I run a cypher query directly on my database, but when I run Spring's built in `findByFieldTitle` it throws an error and says the relationships don't match up.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
Here is the stack trace:

```
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.DatabaseException: Expected 
RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Nodes: ['  rootNodeIds@7'], Predicates: ['id(`  rootNodeIds@7`) IN $rootNodeIds']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),AggregatingQueryProjection(Map(),Map(  n@87 -> FunctionInvocation(Namespace(List()),FunctionName(collect),false,Vector(Variable(  rootNodeIds@7)))),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87'], Optional Matches: : ['QueryGraph {Rels: ['(  NODE105)--[relationshipIds]--(  NODE126)'], Predicates: ['id(relationshipIds) IN $relationshipIds']}']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),AggregatingQueryProjection(Map(  n@87 -> Variable(  n@87)),Map(__sr__ -> FunctionInvocation(Namespace(List()),FunctionName(collect),true,Vector(Variable(relationshipIds)))),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87', '__sr__'], Optional Matches: : ['QueryGraph {Nodes: ['relatedNodeIds'], Predicates: ['id(relatedNodeIds) IN $relatedNodeIds']}']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),AggregatingQueryProjection(Map(  n@87 -> Variable(  n@87), __sr__ -> Variable(__sr__)),Map(__srn__ -> FunctionInvocation(Namespace(List()),FunctionName(collect),true,Vector(Variable(relatedNodeIds)))),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87', '__sr__', '__srn__']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),UnwindProjection(  rootNodeIds@384,Variable(  n@87)),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87', '  rootNodeIds@384', '__sr__', '__srn__']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),RegularQueryProjection(Map(  n@416 -> Variable(  rootNodeIds@384), __sr__ -> Variable(__sr__), __srn__ -> Variable(__srn__)),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@416', '__sr__', '__srn__']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),RegularQueryProjection(Map(__sn__ -> Variable(  n@416), __sr__ -> Variable(__sr__), __srn__ -> Variable(__srn__)),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),None,None)),None)),None)),None)),None)),None) 


Instead, got: 
RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Nodes: ['  rootNodeIds@7'], Predicates: ['id(`  rootNodeIds@7`) IN $rootNodeIds']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),AggregatingQueryProjection(Map(),Map(  n@87 -> FunctionInvocation(Namespace(List()),FunctionName(collect),false,Vector(Variable(  rootNodeIds@7)))),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87'], Optional Matches: : ['QueryGraph {}']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),AggregatingQueryProjection(Map(  n@87 -> Variable(  n@87)),Map(__sr__ -> FunctionInvocation(Namespace(List()),FunctionName(collect),true,Vector(Variable(relationshipIds)))),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87', '__sr__'], Optional Matches: : ['QueryGraph {Nodes: ['relatedNodeIds'], Predicates: ['id(relatedNodeIds) IN $relatedNodeIds']}']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),AggregatingQueryProjection(Map(  n@87 -> Variable(  n@87), __sr__ -> Variable(__sr__)),Map(__srn__ -> FunctionInvocation(Namespace(List()),FunctionName(collect),true,Vector(Variable(relatedNodeIds)))),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87', '__sr__', '__srn__']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),UnwindProjection(  rootNodeIds@384,Variable(  n@87)),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87', '  rootNodeIds@384', '__sr__', '__srn__']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),RegularQueryProjection(Map(  n@416 -> Variable(  rootNodeIds@384), __sr__ -> Variable(__sr__), __srn__ -> Variable(__srn__)),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@416', '__sr__', '__srn__']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),RegularQueryProjection(Map(__sn__ -> Variable(  n@416), __sr__ -> Variable(__sr__), __srn__ -> Variable(__srn__)),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),None,None)),None)),None)),None)),None)),None)


Differences:
 - Tail
    A: Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87'], Optional Matches: : ['QueryGraph {Rels: ['(  NODE105)--[relationshipIds]--(  NODE126)'], Predicates: ['id(relationshipIds) IN $relationshipIds']}']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),AggregatingQueryProjection(Map(  n@87 -> Variable(  n@87)),Map(__sr__ -> FunctionInvocation(Namespace(List()),FunctionName(collect),true,Vector(Variable(relationshipIds)))),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87', '__sr__'], Optional Matches: : ['QueryGraph {Nodes: ['relatedNodeIds'], Predicates: ['id(relatedNodeIds) IN $relatedNodeIds']}']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),AggregatingQueryProjection(Map(  n@87 -> Variable(  n@87), __sr__ -> Variable(__sr__)),Map(__srn__ -> FunctionInvocation(Namespace(List()),FunctionName(collect),true,Vector(Variable(relatedNodeIds)))),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87', '__sr__', '__srn__']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),UnwindProjection(  rootNodeIds@384,Variable(  n@87)),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87', '  rootNodeIds@384', '__sr__', '__srn__']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),RegularQueryProjection(Map(  n@416 -> Variable(  rootNodeIds@384), __sr__ -> Variable(__sr__), __srn__ -> Variable(__srn__)),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@416', '__sr__', '__srn__']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),RegularQueryProjection(Map(__sn__ -> Variable(  n@416), __sr__ -> Variable(__sr__), __srn__ -> Variable(__srn__)),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),None,None)),None)),None)),None)),None))
    B: Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87'], Optional Matches: : ['QueryGraph {}']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),AggregatingQueryProjection(Map(  n@87 -> Variable(  n@87)),Map(__sr__ -> FunctionInvocation(Namespace(List()),FunctionName(collect),true,Vector(Variable(relationshipIds)))),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87', '__sr__'], Optional Matches: : ['QueryGraph {Nodes: ['relatedNodeIds'], Predicates: ['id(relatedNodeIds) IN $relatedNodeIds']}']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),AggregatingQueryProjection(Map(  n@87 -> Variable(  n@87), __sr__ -> Variable(__sr__)),Map(__srn__ -> FunctionInvocation(Namespace(List()),FunctionName(collect),true,Vector(Variable(relatedNodeIds)))),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87', '__sr__', '__srn__']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),UnwindProjection(  rootNodeIds@384,Variable(  n@87)),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@87', '  rootNodeIds@384', '__sr__', '__srn__']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),RegularQueryProjection(Map(  n@416 -> Variable(  rootNodeIds@384), __sr__ -> Variable(__sr__), __srn__ -> Variable(__srn__)),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),Some(RegularSinglePlannerQuery(QueryGraph {Arguments: ['  n@416', '__sr__', '__srn__']},InterestingOrder(RequiredOrderCandidate(List()),List()),RegularQueryProjection(Map(__sn__ -> Variable(  n@416), __sr__ -> Variable(__sr__), __srn__ -> Variable(__srn__)),QueryPagination(None,None),Selections(Set())),None,None)),None)),None)),None)),None))
```

Comment: can you add the exception or even better share a reproducer?

Comment: @meistermeier Added stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your mapping / model The problem is in the version of Neo4j you are using. It has a query planner bug. I do not know when it appeared but it is solved with 4.3.3 / 4.2.10 and higher.

This combined with some needed query improvements in SDN 6.1.6 lead to the problematic constellation right now. I would suggest to manually set the Spring Data Neo4j version down to 6.1.5 if you cannot upgrade the database.

(This is copied from [Spring Data neo4j access relationship from both sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69740034/spring-data-neo4j-access-relationship-from-both-sides) but this question is not a duplicate.)

Comment: My current version of neo4j is 4.3.5

Comment: That was the issue, I had installed neo4j through command line and also neo4j desktop. neo4j desktop was an using an older version. Soon as I switched my database to use my command line installation it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: helped me with neo 3.5.5, thanks a lot